# Select a date from Jquery, date picker using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

1. Go to the Official Website of Jquery https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

It's not allow be to click on input text even it's have unique id="datepicker" getting an error element not found Exception but  when i runs locally  by adding jquery date picker  it works likes a charm. can somebody help me can't able to figure it out!

2) By using this url i can select anything but it not works with jquery official site as i mentioned above https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/default.html

Below is my actual code that is not getting work

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\ProgramFiles\\chromedriver.exe");

      driver=new ChromeDriver();
      driver.manage().window().maximize();
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      driver.get("https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/");
      Thread.sleep(5000);
      driver.findElement(By.id("datepicker")).click();
```

Comment: Change your URL to https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/default.html and then try

Comment: Why should i Change my URL

Comment: Because the datepicker is inside a IFrame and I am giving you the direct URL of IFrame so you can test your logic. Else use what you saw  in @DebanjanB answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element with `id="datepicker"` is within a `frame`. So we have to switch to the intended `frame` first, then locate the element and then call the `click()` method as follows:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/");
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@class='demo-frame'][@src='/resources/demos/datepicker/default.html']")));
driver.findElement(By.id("datepicker")).click();
System.out.println("Datepicker Clicked");
```