# Cannot select a date range from jquery datepicker date range selector in Selenium JAVA

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm struggling with selecting a date range from jquery datepicker date range selector using selenium web driver.

Following image shows the date picker.

[image: calendar]

I need to select a date range from this calendar. I've tried following links.

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45592152/select-a-date-from-jquery-date-picker-using-selenium-webdriver)

[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21422548/how-to-select-the-date-picker-in-selenium-webdriver)

Only thing i found relevant is the following code segment.

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@class='demo-frame'][@src='/resources/demos/datepicker/default.html']")));
driver.findElement(By.id("datepicker")).click();
System.out.println("Datepicker Clicked");
```

But, it doesn't show how to select a date range from the date picker.

Thanks in advance. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, it makes no sense to interact with such components via `findElement` calls. Unless you want to make your tests unstable. Such datepickers usually have public API, which could be accessed directly via `JavascriptExecutor`. Quick [sample](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate):

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "setDate", "10/12/2012" );
```

could be used the following way:

```
executeScript("$( '.selector' ).datepicker( 'setDate', '10/12/2012' );");
```

So I'd recommend you to find out which JS library is used to render your datepicker, check their API, and access it directly the way I've written above.

Answer (score -1):

Give a try to below code and lets see if it works.
I stole the code from [select the Date Picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21422548/how-to-select-the-date-picker-in-selenium-webdriver)

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript ("document.getElementById('elementid').removeAttribute('readonly',0);"); // Enables the from date box

WebElement dateBox= driver.findElement(By.id("elementid"));
dateBox.clear();
dateBox.sendKeys("8-Dec-2014"); //Enter date in required format
```

Comment: What is this dateBox?

Comment: I don't have a text field to type the date. Only the calendar

Comment: can you give URL?

Comment: rephrase your question so that appropriate person can help you.

Comment: What date you want to select?

Comment: Today's date and next month same date. :)